# Blueprism combobox is not working for HTML

Tags: html, combobox, blueprism

Error Screenshot Included:
Combobox value got changed from 10 to 100 in HTML but the number of elements in the Table is not increased from 10 to 100 please guide me with suitable answers

[image]

I have Spy the Combobox in HTML and updated the value using the `Navigate
* Element = combo box spy element`, `Action = SelectItem`, `ItemValue = 4`

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Most likely a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606099/handling-multiple-html-combo-boxes-in-blueprism