# Handling multiple html combo boxes in BluePrism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

On a web page there are two html combo boxes, value in the second combo box depends on the values selected in first combo. When I do this manually it works, but with BluePrism on selecting value in first box the values in second combo box doesn't load.

Comment: Can you add some code/example you've been experimenting with?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it be so, that when you're using blueprism "select item" action instead of clicking using mouse, then some javascript code must not be executed.

I'd try to investigate a page that you're automating. I'd search for the javascript code that is being executed when using mouse and try to call that method from BluePrism object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it be so, that when you're using blueprism "select item" action instead of >clicking using mouse, then some javascript code must not be executed.

Yes, this is the right answer. 
Also, some combo box will check your manipulation. If your manipulation is more robot-like, it would not invoke the javascript code. You may need to use "invoke javascript function" in navigating stage or you can just use "global send keys" to send keystroke and make you manipulation more human-like.

Answer (score 0):

When you spy the element of same type just like combo box or text box you, please select the appropriate attribute from modeler window. In this case you can able to select the attribute "`ordinal`" and "`match index`".

If you check ordinal value will different for each combo box.

Answer (score -1):

Is it something like, if I choose first option in ComboBox1 then in ComboBox2 there will be automaticly chossen option 2? Is it allways the same conection?

If so, choose ComboBox 1, then make a descision step: IF CoboBox1 IS 1 THEN...

If not, then after you choose ComboBox 1, you may wish to read value of that ComboBox and then choose the value of the other.

Hope it helps.